# Sharepoint consume webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I am having some issues with calling the asmx webservices that are installed by default when installing the wss 3.0 (Sharepoint 2007 I think) on the server.

Our sharepoint is using forms authentication.
In IIS I can see the website and in that site the virtual directory "_vti_bin" exists (this is were the webservices are located.)

I can browse without problems to the WSDL, so I can add it to my web references in my visual studio solution (I used the "web reference" instead of "service reference" method to add the reference to my solution).
I can't browse to the asmx webservice itself, it keeps redirecting to the login page.

In my code, I tried to use the Authentication asmx service, but I can't seem to consume it correctly..

This is my code:

```
    protected Cookie _authCookie;
    CookieContainer _cookieContainer;

    using (Authentication spAuthentication = new Authentication())
        {
            spAuthentication.Url = "https://sharepointserverxx.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx";
            spAuthentication.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            //spAuthentication.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            spAuthentication.PreAuthenticate = true;

            LoginResult loginResult = spAuthentication.Login(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            _authCookie = new Cookie();

            if (loginResult.ErrorCode == LoginErrorCode.NoError)
            {
                CookieCollection cookies = spAuthentication.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(spAuthentication.Url));
                _authCookie = cookies[loginResult.CookieName];
                _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                _cookieContainer.Add(_authCookie);
                return true;
            }
            else
                txtResult.Text = "Invalid Username/Password while authenticating to the sharepoint webservices.";
            return false;
        }
```

I am getting the following error on the line with the following code:

```
LoginResult loginResult = spAuthentication.Login(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

### Error: The request failed with the error message:

Object moved to < href="https://sharepointserverxx.com/_layouts/1033/error.aspx?ErrorText=Failed%20to%20Execute%20URL%2E">here

I think that my webservice call is always redirected to the login page of sharepoint.. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

If I uncomment the following line, I get another error "Error: Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'." (because the response is the html page of the login page)

```
//spAuthentication.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

Comment: Hello, I don't think our sharepoint has any other sites / collections except for the root website.. How can I know for sure? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving might have multiple causes. You should enable Verbose logging in Sharepoint (in Central Administration => Operations) to see the exact error.

Are you running on IIS7? There are some compatibility problems with asmx handlers on IIS7 in Classic mode. Can you try adding missing httpHandlers in the Web.Config of your sharepoint website?

```
<system.web><httpHandlers>
<remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" /> 

<add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 

<add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 


<add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" /> 

<add verb="*" path="_vti_bin/ReportServer" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Soap.RSProxyHttpHandler, RSSharePointSoapProxy, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> 

<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebPart.axd" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts.WebPartHttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> 
</httpHandlers></system.web>
```

Comment: Hi, that was exactly the problem :) I added the *.asmx entry in the httpHandlers of the sharepoint web.config and the webservices are working like a charm :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your issue is due to the to _vti_bin needing to be relative to the current server and site collection.

This is code I call in my class constructor to set up all the services I need.

```
    // Server URL is the root server E.G.
    // I set mine in class constructor
    String serverUrl = "http://192.168.100.10:1234/";

    /// <summary>
    /// Web referenced must be relative to the site collection you are seeking to query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="siteCollectionUrl"></param>
    private void SetWebReferencePaths(string siteCollectionUrl)
    {
        string siteUrl = serverUrl;

        if (!siteUrl.EndsWith("/"))
            siteUrl += "/";

        if (!siteCollectionUrl.EndsWith("/"))
            siteCollectionUrl += "/";

        string fullPath = "";

        if (siteUrl != siteCollectionUrl)
        {
            fullPath = siteUrl + siteCollectionUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            fullPath = siteUrl;
        }

        listServiceUrl        = fullPath + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        groupsServiceUrl      = fullPath + "_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx";
        permissionsServiceUrl = fullPath + "_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx";
        siteDataServiceUrl    = fullPath + "_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx";
        websServiceUrl        = fullPath + "_vti_bin/Webs.asmx";
        listServiceUrl        = fullPath + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        groupsServiceUrl      = fullPath + "_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx";
        permissionsServiceUrl = fullPath + "_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx";
        siteDataServiceUrl    = fullPath + "_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx";
        websServiceUrl        = fullPath + "_vti_bin/Webs.asmx";
        // result would look like
        // http://sharep2007/SiteDirectory/FirstSite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
        // It's broken down like this
        // http://sharep2007/ + SiteDirectory/FirstSite/ + _vti_bin/Lists.asmx
        // serverURL + siteCollectionURL + _vti_bin/Lists.asmx
    }
```

Then when I call the a service I do it like this:

```
using (ShareLists.Lists listService = new Lists())
{
    listService.Url = listServiceUrl;
    // Code using service
}
```

Comment: Hello, I don't think our sharepoint has any other sites / collections except for the root website.. How can I know this for sure? Thx.

Comment: @Rise_against you can tell by the URL in your bar. I just created a new site on my root sharepoint site and it looked like this `http://sharep2007/SiteDirectory/FirstSite/default.aspx` so targeting its webservice would need this URL `http://sharep2007/SiteDirectory/FirstSite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`

You should at the very least have user sites (when you login and click the "MySite" button) e.g. `http://sharep2007/personal/myusername/`

Comment: You can also create your own custom named collections though such as `http://sharep2007/MyTestCollection/MySiteName`

Comment: Hi, I just have the root site, there are no subsites. I just created a new subsite called "Test" and changed the webservice call to "https://sharepointserverxx.com/Test/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx", but I have the same error..

Comment: @Rise_against can you navigate to the URL in your browser? (And see the web service methods listed)